# Что будет если продолжительность выполнения задачи больше ее периодичности по расписанию?

Tags: cron, crontab

Есть задача, которая выполняется по расписанию раз в 5 минут. Что будет если время ее выполнения больше 5 минут?

Будет выполняться уже две задачи параллельно или же если задание не завершено, то второй процесс не запуститься?

Есть ли нюансы например общий лог или что-то еще?

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php /........../5min.php >/...../logfile.log 2>&1
```

Comment: А какие основания у планировщика НЕ запускать задание? он же не телепат, а инициативы, даже разумной, от него ждать бессмысленно. Сказано запустить - запустит, а там хоть трава не расти. Если хотите избежать параллельных запусков - то заставьте этой проблемой заниматься само задание, пусть ищет работающий процесс-копию, и если найдёт, то завершает работу.

Comment: Я наоборот не против чтобы он запустил их параллельно если один процесс не завершен. Просто интересно само поведение планировщика в этом случае.

Comment: Представьте себя на месте программиста, пишущего cron. У него два варианта - запретить или разрешить запуск задания, если предыдущее не завершилось. При этом понимаем, что юзеру может быть надо и так, и эдак. Если разрешим, а юзеру не надо - он в задании может организовать завершение дубликата. А вот если запретим, а юзеру надо - то ничегошеньки он сделать не сможет... нехорошо это, правда? и как вменяемый программист, Вы выберете вариант с разрешением, чтобы потом юзеры своими мыслями о Вас не портили Вашу карму...

Comment: @Akina скажите уже внятно, крон на самом деле так себя ведёт и это где-то документировано, или это всего лишь ваши рассуждения?)

Comment: @andreymal Вы правы, это только мои рассуждения. Нигде в мануале, даже расширенном, такие тонкости вроде бы не описаны. Однако - это всё-таки программное средство, которое не может содержать в коде некие специфичные для определённой среды возможности. А в общем случае определить, выполняется задача или завершена, невозможно. Следовательно, такой возможности, как контроль, завершено ли задание, в программу заложено быть не может. В том числе и из-за неопределённости понятия "задание завершено" - если запущенный заданием модуль породил дочку, а сам завершился, то задание завершено или нет?

Comment: @Akina магическая фраза «по историческим причинам» может обосновать любой бред, который может твориться внутри крона на практике, несмотря на верность ваших теоретических рассуждений)

Comment: Это Вы к тому, что проще и быстрее попробовать?

Comment: Вообще идеальным ответом на данный вопрос была бы какая-нибудь цитата из документации. Попробовать, наверно, тоже можно, но есть опасность упущения каких-нибудь важных нюансов, влияющих на поведение (например, зависимость от конкретной реализации крона, которых в том же дебиане целых несколько)

Comment: В общем попробовал и запустил задание с частотой раз в минуту, которое просто пишет в лог и в файл время своего запуска каждые 10 секунд. Живет это задание 5 минут. В результате оказалось, что вы правы и задания выполняются параллельно - пишут в файл все 5 из запущенных скриптов.

Answer (score 2):

наиболее популярная версия программы *cron* — [*isc cron*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#Modern_versions), ведёт себя именно так, как и описано в документации — запускает запланированные пользователями задания.

ни о каком **контроле** за «дублированием заданий» в документации ничего не сказано. соответственно, и программа *cron* этим **не занимается**.

---

сей факт легко проверяем. создайте, например, ежеминутное задание на запуск программы *sleep* с интервалом больше одной минуты (чтобы предыдущий экземпляр ещё работал к моменту запуска следующего):

```
* * * * * sleep 150
```

и через пару минут произойдёт запуск уже двух экземпляров программы *sleep*:

```
$ ps fax
...
 1535 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/cron -f
 3162 ?        S      0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/CRON -f
 3163 ?        Ss     0:00  |   \_ /bin/sh -c sleep 150
 3164 ?        S      0:00  |       \_ sleep 150
 3169 ?        S      0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/CRON -f
 3170 ?        Ss     0:00  |   \_ /bin/sh -c sleep 150
 3171 ?        S      0:00  |       \_ sleep 150
...
```

не забудьте убрать это тестовое задание по окончании проверки.

---

если запускаемой программе (скрипту) необходим подобный контроль, то она должна заниматься этим **самостоятельно**.